# Accessing a service on the PROPER IP running in docker container on a Linux host

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ip, influxdb, k6

My problem is specific to k6 and InfluxDB, but i think the root cause is more general.

I'm using the official k6 distribution and its [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/k6io/k6/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) to run Grafana and InfluxDB which i start with the `docker-compose up -d influxdb grafana` command.

Grafana dashboard is accessible from localhost:3000, but running k6 with the recommended command `$ docker run -i loadimpact/k6 run --out influxdb=http://localhost:8086/myk6db - <script.js` (following [this](https://k6.io/docs/results-visualization/influxdb-+-grafana#run-the-test-and-upload-the-results-to-influxdb) guide) k6 throws the following error (on Linux and MacOS as well):

```
level=error msg="InfluxDB: Couldn't write stats" error="Post \"http://localhost:8086/write?consistency=&db=myk6db&precision=ns&rp=\": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8086: connect: connection refused"
```

I tried the command with localhost and 127.0.0.1 as well for InfluxDB as well. Also with IP addresses returned by `docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' k6_influxdb_1` It either failed with the above error or didnt work, which means k6 didn't complain, but no data appeared in InfluxDB.

*However*, if i query the "internal IP" address which the network interface is using (with `ifconfig` command) and use that IP (192.168.1.66), everything works fine:

```
docker run -i loadimpact/k6 run --out influxdb=http://192.168.1.66:8086/k6db  - <test.js
```

So my **questions** are:

1. Why does Grafana work fine with localhost:3000 and InfluxDB with localhost:8086 doesn't?
2. Why does only the "internal IP" work and no other IP?

I know there is a similar question, but that doesn't answer mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers run in an isolated network space.  Docker can maintain internal networks, and there is Compose syntax to create them.

If you're making a call to a Docker container from outside Docker space but on the same host, you can usually connect to it as `localhost`, and the first port number listed in the Compose `ports:` section.  If you look at the `docker-compose.yml` file you link to, it lists `ports: [3000:3000]`, so port 3000 on the host forwards to port 3000 in the container; and if you're calling `http://localhost:3000` from a browser on the same host, that will reach that forwarded port.

Otherwise, calls from one container to another can generally use the container's name (as in `docker run --name`) or the Compose service name; but, they must be on the same Docker network.  That `docker-compose.yml` file also lists

```yaml
services:
  influxdb:
    networks:
      - k6
      - grafana
```

so you can reach `http://influxdb:8086` using the service's normal port number, provided the calling container is on one of those two networks.  If the service has `ports:`, they're not considered for inter-container calls.

In the Docker documentation, [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has more details on this setup.

There's one final trick that can help you run the specific command you're trying to run.  [`docker-compose run`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/) will run a one-off command, using the setup for some container in the `docker-compose.yml`, except without its `ports:` and replacing its `command:`.  The `docker-compose.yml` file you reference includes a `k6` container, on the `k6` network, running the `loadimpact/k6` image.  So you can probably run

```sh
docker-compose run k6 \
  run --out influxdb=http://influxdb:8086/myk6db - \
  <script.js
```

(And probably the `K6_OUT` environment variable in the `docker-compose.yml` can supply that `--out` option for you.)

You shouldn't ever need to look up the container-private IP addresses.  They aren't usable in a variety of common scenarios, and in between Docker networking for calls between containers and published ports for calls from outside Docker, there are better ways to make calls to containers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the constructive tone and details! I'm not sure if you were going for this, but i just realized that k6 was not running. So Grafana and InfluxDB were up, but not k6. Running k6 with `docker run` was not enough to have k6 on the network InfluxDB was. Using the `docker-compose run` command you suggested last solves this.